# keras RNN with characters input fails to predict

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I am working on an RNN that must predict a number from a string.
Basically, I have a list of strings, and a float is associated to each string. The strings, which are not words and may seem random, are in fact ordered and have logic. Thus the associated float is completely predictable.

My strategy for this problem is to convert each character of the string in a number, with `ord(character)` and put all the strings in a NumPy array.

As a first test, I created a very easy set of strings, only containing "a" and "b" characters. The logic is very simple. The more there are "a" in the string, the higher the associated number. Unfortunately, the RNN completely fails.

**Training data preparation:**

```
a = "abbbbb"
b = "aabbbb"
c = "aaabbb"
d = "aaaabb"
e = "aaaaab"
f = "aaaaaa"

X_train = []
X_train.append([ord(letter) for letter in a]) # Converts "abbbbb" to [97, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98]
X_train.append([ord(letter) for letter in b])
X_train.append([ord(letter) for letter in c])
X_train.append([ord(letter) for letter in d])
X_train.append([ord(letter) for letter in e])
X_train.append([ord(letter) for letter in f])

X_train = np.array(X_train)
X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 1))

y_train = [0, 5, 15, 30, 50, 80]
```

**RNN implementation and training**

This is one of many RNN I tried. I tried changing the number of layers, the number of units per layer, and the Dropout. Without success.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Dropout
import math
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

regressor = Sequential()

regressor.add(LSTM(units=256, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], 1)))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))
regressor.add(LSTM(units=256, return_sequences=True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))
regressor.add(LSTM(units=256, return_sequences=True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))
regressor.add(LSTM(units=256, return_sequences=True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))
regressor.add(LSTM(units=256, return_sequences=True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))
regressor.add(LSTM(units=256, return_sequences=False))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))
regressor.add(Dense(units=1))

regressor.compile(optimizer = "adam", loss = "mean_squared_error")

regressor.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=32)
```

**Test data preparation and prediction**

```
X_test = list(ord(letter) for letter in f)
X_test = np.array(X_test)
X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (1, X_test.shape[0], 1))

prediction = regressor.predict(X_test)
```

**THE PROBLEM**

I tested the RNN with different strings, even with the 6 strings from the training set. The RNN prediction is always the same, 30.0094, no matter what is the input. The two last decimals can vary, but basically, the output will always be 30.00xx.

The number 30 is not any number since it is the mean of the y_train list, [0, 5, 15, 30, 50, 80]

I tried with different y_train lists, I always obtain the mean...

Any idea on what is going on ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with a way simple architecture?

```
regressor = Sequential()

regressor.add(LSTM(units=1, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], 1)))
regressor.compile(optimizer = "adam", loss = "mean_squared_error")  
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=5, batch_size=1)
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, with the only modification being `return_sequences=False`. The predicted value is 0.999988, no matter the input string... I tried overfitting this model with 5000 epochs. The prediction on the training set still give 0.999988. I then tried building a model by adding one layer of 64 units on top of your suggested model. Still got a prediction around 1. Then I tried with 2 layers of 128 units on top of your suggested model. Still a prediction around 1...